# File type is not validated

Tags: yii

I'm trying to validate file type before saving it to database. This is my rule

```
array('picture', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png, jpeg', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'maxSize'=>1024*1024/*1mb*/, 'tooLarge'=>Yii::t('default', 'File is too large'), 'on'=>'create'),
```

I'm trying to upload multiple images

```
foreach($_FILES["picture"]["name"] as $key=>$value)
{
    $images->picture='file';
    $images->IDbuyitnow=1;
    if($images->validate())
        echo $value." ";
    else
        echo "doesnt work";
}
```

HTML code

```
<?php echo CHtml::fileField('picture[]','',array('class'=>'form-control' ,'multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*')); ?>
```

I know I should use CMultiUpload but I wanted to make it like that. But it always validate it even if $images->picture="file" or "25.docx". var_dump($images->validate()) returns true

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] Weirdest thing ever, attribute shouldn't be called "picture" but "image" instead.

**FULL SOLUTION**

HTML

```
<?php echo CHtml::fileField('image_file[]','',array('class'=>'form-control' ,'multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*')); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$images=new BuyItNowImage;
$file=CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image_file');
foreach($fileas $key=>$value)
{
    $images->image_file=$value;
    $images->IDbuyitnow=1;

    if($images->validate())
        echo "ok";
    else
        echo "not ok";

}
```

MODEL

```
array('image_file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png, jpeg', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'maxSize'=>1024*1024/*1mb*/, 'tooLarge'=>Yii::t('default', 'File is too large')),
```